# How can I preserve the position of Drag and Drop elements?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

In the second tab on my test website (`http://109.201.141.20/DragAndDropTest/default.aspx`), I can Drag elements from the box "Available Room Class" (on the left side) into the box "Rooms Class In Your Hotel" (on theright side). However, when I do this and then change to a different tab and then change back, all the data has been reset: all elements are back in the left box. This is in spite of the fact that changing between tabs does not reload the page. How can I fix that?

Comment: you can use cookies to store the position of each drag element

Comment: Hello Roi. If your test website ever goes offline, or if it is changed to fix your current problems, this question will become nonsensical. We want to build up canonical answers to questions here on Stack Overflow, which is why we want questions to be self-contained. Please edit this question to include enough code to reproduce the problem, or it will probably be closed and, ultimately, deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you click on the second tab (#liRoomTypes) it reloads the html for #dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer2 div. (check line 34)

It would be better to add that html into the body of the index page and set the the display to none, then when you click on the second tab, you hide the first tab content and just show the second one.